# Encadeamento - R

Tags: r

Possuo dois datas frames, um contendo dados de produtos e outro contendo dados de loja, porem não possuo variáveis de referencia entre eles (o que não me permitiria um inner join), minha necessidade é apresentar para cada um destes produtos em questão o codigo de cada uma das lojas, como no caso abaixo:

```
LOJA Produto

1    camera 

1    Smartphone

1    TV

2    camera

2    Smartphone

2    TV

.    .

.    .
```

.    .

.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Caso suas informações sejam parecidas com o que está no resultado esperado,

```
LOJA = 1:3
Produtos = c("camera", "Smartphone", "TV")
```

um `merge` resolve.

```
dados <- merge(LOJA, Produtos)
library(dplyr)
dados <- arrange(dados, x)
names(dados) <- c("LOJA", "Produtos")
```

Aqui o resultado do código acima

```
  LOJA   Produtos
     1     camera
     1 Smartphone
     1         TV
     2     camera
     2 Smartphone
     2         TV
     3     camera
     3 Smartphone
     3         TV
```

Answer (score 3):

Com os dados do Rafael, será mais simples usar a função `expand.grid`.

```
LOJA = 1:3
Produtos = c("camera", "Smartphone", "TV")

res <- expand.grid(LOJA = LOJA, Produtos = Produtos)[, 2:1]
res
```